# How to set focus on rich-text-field, in edit-mode of a contenttype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, focus, plone

I'd like to initially set the focus onto the text-field of an item when editing it, but cannot overcome TinymMCE'S iframe kickin' in. When disableling TinyMCE, everything works as expected, the text-field is focusable. I tried simulating a click in TinyMCE's body-element, no luck either. Is it possible at all, to focus the body-field via JS?

This is what I tried so far:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#text').focus()          // Only works, when TinyMCE is disabled.

        $('body#content').click() // Cannot click into TinyMCE's body.

        $('#text_bold').click() // Cannot even click one of the editor's buttons.

        setTimeout(function() {
                            // Tried same as above with time-delay, no luck.
        }, 277);
    });

    $(window).load(function() {
                      // Tried the same as in doc.ready, no luck.
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: share some relevant code so that we can help you better.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar: Updated quest with code-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE is loaded inside an IFRAME so it's not in the DOM of the main document. Direct jQuery calls will not work.

This is an old code I used (TinyMCE version shipped with Plone 4.3):

```js
(function($) {

    function checkTinyMCELoaded () {

        if (window.tinymce==undefined || !tinymce.editors.length) {
            setTimeout(checkTinyMCELoaded, 100);
            return;
        }

        $('#text_ifr').contents().find(".mceContentBody").get(0).focus();

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(checkTinyMCELoaded, 100);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

It's **ugly**. Best way is to get rid of `setTimeout` and attach an handler on TinyMCE load event, but when I looked into this I found this is not so easy on Plone as you must change the `.init()` call of TinyMCE done by Plone JS.

Comment: Ja ugly, but works! Thanks for the hint to Plone's init(), that would have been the next step to take, but you saved me of it, mille grazie!

Comment: P.S.: The if-statement causes a "too much recursion"-error now, allthough it used to work. Maybe loading the form via jQ's load-wrapper mingles in here.

Comment: P.P.S.: That was my bad, I'd passed an additional parameter, which got looped through other functions, as well, which caused the infinite recursion. Fixed that and your snippet works perfectly fine again, now.

Comment: To get the text that's been entered into the TinyMCE window, would that be `my_text = $('#text_ifr').contents().find(".mceContentBody").get(0).val();` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of old but I definitely struggled finding a solution for this online, so I'm sharing. Add this, in your tinymce.init() codeblock. Change selector or event if needed.

```
selector: "textarea.tinymce",
setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('mouseup', function (e) {
        this.focus();
    });
}
```